# Команды копирования в HDFS и запуска бинарника

Tags: unix, map-reduce, solaris, c++, linux

Hadoop у меня располагается в `/export/hadoop-1.0.1`, а запускаемая программа -`/export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/c++/hadoopc++/src/hadoopc++.cpp`. Тогда согласно

- [C/C++ MapReduce Code & build](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/C%2B%2BWordCount),
- [Running C++ Programs on Hadoop](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%2B%2B_Programs_on_Hadoop)

- как будут выглядить команды копирования бинарного файла (`/export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/c++/parindex`) в HDFS (также возникает вопрос, надо ли копировать туда же входные файлы программы) и запуска бинарника? На команду root@one: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/c++:#hadoop fs -mkdir bin
выдает ошибку
bash: hadoop: command not found (даже не удается создать папку для дальнейшего копирования)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В папке есть /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin есть скрипт hadoop и через него выполняются все команды, например, ./hadoop fs -mkdir bin.

Comment: Добавьте в PATH export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin и не мучайтесь.